# Working with Ninja Form data on Wordpress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, ninja

I have users submitting a form via Ninja Form on my Wordpress page. I would like to work with the variables lately.

Being specific, counting the data entered.

I got this code in a PHP snippet:

```
$form_id = 1;

// Get all submissions for that form ID
$submissions = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_subs();
if ( is_array( $submissions ) && count( $submissions ) > 0 ) {
    foreach($submissions as $submission) {
        // Grabbing all fields
        $values = $submission->get_field_values();

// Getting specific fields from above variable
        $jmeno = $value['jmeno'];


        // Output your fields here

        echo "$jmeno";


    }
}

However, I am not getting any results back. Any ideas?

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$value['jmeno']` to `$values['jmeno']`.